# Gauge transformation on a principal bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, vector-bundles, gauge-theory

I am reading through lecture notes found [here](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect1.pdf) and on pg 11 they define a map $\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}:\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\rightarrow G$ by

$\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(p)=g_{\alpha}(\Phi(p))g_{\alpha}(p)^{-1}$,

where $\Phi:P\rightarrow P$ is a gauge transformation of a principal bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow M$.

Then about halfway down pg 12 the author justifies a line of working by claiming

$g_{\alpha}(p)=\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(p)g_{\alpha}(q)$,

where $q=\Phi^{-1}(p)$. But this surely must be incorrect since the equality above is equivalent to

$\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(p)=g_{\alpha}(p)g_{\alpha}(q)^{-1}=g_{\alpha}(\Phi(q))g_{\alpha}(q)^{-1}=\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(q)$

which is not possible since $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism?

The reason this worries me is because he uses this relationship in the next line to justify another step. So either I am missing something or the author has a typo and now I need to go and figure out what it is they actually meant.

If anyone could shed some light on this it would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what was probably intended.
Observe that $\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(q)=g_{\alpha}(p)g_{\alpha}(q)^{-1}$. Thus $g_{\alpha}(p)=\overline{\phi}_{\alpha}(q)g_{\alpha}(q)$.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought was going on... I'll run with that... it's just the author does it again 1 line down... weird